# iRobot Create2 Programmable Robot: what is already in the robot

Tags: irobot-create

I want to buy the programmable iRobot Create2 and I have some questions about:

- The "autonomous navigation" with obstacle avoidance is just implemented in the robot when I'll buy it?
- And what about the "come back home" in case of discharge? Is already disponible?
- What are the sensors already inside the robot? Infrared and leds only?
  Thanks in avance

Comment: Welcome to Robotics:SE. What has your research shown you so far? You might find it helpful to review the site [tour](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/tour) and [Help Centre](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help) and, in particular, [ask].

Answer (score 1):

Create 2 has all of the same navigation features and sensors as our Roomba 600 series vacuum cleaning robots. That is to say, it does not have systematic navigation or obstacle avoidance. You may confine it using virtual walls. If your project requires automatic room coverage, such as a roving security bot, you can make use of the built-in coverage algorithm by starting a cleaning cycle through the Open Interface.

Create will return to the dock when its battery is low only if you have it running a cleaning cycle. If you are directly commanding the wheels yourself, it will not automatically return to the dock. You will need to monitor the battery state yourself, at which point you can command it to return to the dock.

Sensors available include wheel encoders, downward-facing IR cliff sensors, forward-facing IR light-touch and wall-follow sensors, the IR receiver for dock/virtual wall codes, the dirt-detect sensor, buttons, and the bumper. A number of internal variables such as battery state and motor current are also available. For actuators you have the two wheels, three cleaning motors, and LEDs.

Here is a link to the Create programming manual:
https://www.irobotweb.com/-/media/MainSite/Files/About/STEM/Create/2018-07-19_iRobot_Roomba_600_Open_Interface_Spec.pdf